# mlflow.pytorch.load_model with pytorch_lightning model - predict method not working

Tags: mlflow, pytorch-lightning

I have trained a pytorch_lightning model and when loaded the model successfully it throws me the following error:

**My code:**

```
classifier_model = TextClassifier(backbone="prajjwal1/bert-tiny", num_classes=datamodule.num_classes, metrics=torchmetrics.F1Score(datamodule.num_classes))
trainer = flash.Trainer(max_epochs=3, gpus=torch.cuda.device_count())

MODEL_ARTIFACT_PATH = 'MODEL'
REGISTERED_MODEL_NAME = 'MODEL2'
with mlflow.start_run(experiment_id=experiment.experiment_id, run_name="MYRUN01") as dl_model_tracking_run:
    trainer.finetune(classifier_model, datamodule=datamodule, strategy="freeze")
    trainer.test(dataloaders=datamodule)
    ....
    mlflow.pytorch.log_model(pytorch_model=classifier_model, artifact_path=MODEL_ARTIFACT_PATH, registered_model_name=REGISTERED_MODEL_NAME)

run_id = dl_model_tracking_run.info.run_id
print("run_id: {}; lifecycle_stage: {}".format(run_id,
    mlflow.get_run(run_id).info.lifecycle_stage))

logged_model = f'runs:/{run_id}/{MODEL_ARTIFACT_PATH}'
model = mlflow.pytorch.load_model(logged_model)
model.trainer.state.stage='test'
model.predict({'What a news!'})
```

**Error:**

```
def predict(self, *args, **kwargs):
    raise AttributeError("`flash.Task.predict` has been removed. Use `flash.Trainer.predict` instead.")

AttributeError: `flash.Task.predict` has been removed. Use `flash.Trainer.predict` instead.
```

I checked the mlflow docs in below link and my code seems ok:

https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.pytorch.html

Any Idea how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
datamodule = TextClassificationData.from_lists(
    predict_data=[
        "Turgid dialogue, feeble characterization - Harvey Keitel a judge?.",
        "The worst movie in the history of cinema.",
        "I come from Bulgaria where it 's almost impossible to have a tornado.",
    ],
    batch_size=4,
)
predictions = trainer.predict(model, datamodule=datamodule, output="labels")
```